# Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Failed to run model, Interpreter busy, java.lang.RuntimeException: Interpreter busy

Tags: flutter, visual-studio-code, tensorflow-lite

I am trying to create an android application utilizing the MoveNet model from TFlite. The application is built but the following message occurs. The widgets are loading fine and the app is running on my android phone

[image]

Here are my dependencies:

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  tflite: ^1.1.2
  camera: ^0.9.4+5
```

The concerned code is the following:

```
import 'package:camera/camera.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:tflite/tflite.dart';

import 'main.dart';

class Home extends StatefulWidget {
  Home({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _HomeState createState() => _HomeState();
}

class _HomeState extends State<Home> {
  CameraImage? cameraImage;
  CameraController? cameraController;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    loadCamera();
    loadModel();
  }

  loadCamera() {
    cameraController = CameraController(cameras![1], ResolutionPreset.medium);
    cameraController!.initialize().then((value) {
      if (!mounted) {
        return;
      } else {
        setState(() {
          cameraController!.startImageStream((imageStream) {
            cameraImage = imageStream;
            runModel();
          });
        });
      }
    });
  }

  runModel() async {
    if (cameraImage != null) {
      var predictions = await Tflite.runModelOnFrame(
          bytesList: cameraImage!.planes.map((plane) {
            return plane.bytes;
          }).toList(),
          imageHeight: cameraImage!.height,
          imageWidth: cameraImage!.width,
          imageMean: 127.5,
          imageStd: 127.5,
          rotation: 90,
          numResults: 2,
          threshold: 0.1,
          asynch: true);
      // predictions!.forEach((element) {
      //   print(element);
      // });q
    }
  }

  loadModel() async {
    await Tflite.loadModel(model: "assets/model.tflite");
  }
```

Comment: Can you share the full error log that contains the unhandled platform exception?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like the same issue as in: [Unhandled Exception: PlatformException(Failed to run model, Interpreter busy, java.lang.RuntimeException: Interpreter busy in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67307566/).

The solution to the original question was to stop and run the session again instead of hot reload/start.